# vs code docker adding run arguments like --privileged

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I try to run my containers with --privileged.
I can of course do it manually over terminal with `docker run --privileged ...` but I use VS Code and when I press "Docker: Launch .Net Core (Preview)" it handles `docker run` command itself.

I have tried something like following, but no luck;

```
       {
       "name": "Docker: Launch .NET Core (Preview)",
       "type": "docker-coreclr",
       "request": "launch",
       "preLaunchTask": "build",
       "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/Services/***/***.csproj",
       "appFolder": "${workspaceFolder}/Services/***/",
       "dockerBuild": {},
       "dockerRun": {"network": "host", "runArgs": ["--privileged"]}
   },
```

On Visual Studio, it works when I add the following line to the .csproj "PropertyGroup" tag;

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>--net host --privileged -p 80:8081 -p 443:44342</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried this in VS Code in Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 with Remote-Containers Plugin

In Remote-Containers configuration file: devcontainer.json you can add additional run command parameters, including --privileged.
My config is below.

```
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    ...
    // "remoteUser": "vscode",
    "runArgs": ["--privileged"]
}
```

Location of devcontainer.json is: <my_workspace>/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json

After every change in JSON, you need to execute in VSC

1. F1
2. Remote-Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Containers